# How do you test shortcut using period (".") or comma (",") in combination such as {Shift>}{Alt>}.{/Alt}{/Shift}

Tags: react-testing-library, user-event

Trying to test a key combo of `Shift + Alt + .` and also `Shift + Alt + ,` and I am not able to detect those at all. `Shift + Alt + ArrowLeft` or `Shift + Alt + ArrowRight` work perfectly e.g:

```
await act(
    async () =>
        await user.keyboard('{Shift>}{Alt>}{ArrowRight}{/Alt}{/Shift}'),
);
```

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/testing-library/user-event/blob/7a305dee9ab833d6f338d567fc2e862b4838b76a/src/keyboard/keyMap.ts#L4) it appears those are maybe not handled?